# Unable to display data while trying to Fetch earthquake data from USGS website

Tags: android, listview

Please I need help, Am trying to fetch earthquake data of different locations in the world from the USGS website and display them on a listView, but after making my HttpRequest on the JSON link and fetching the data from the JSON link, my app was unable to pull the data and leaves the screen blank without any message of crash when run.
Here is the JSON link < http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&orderby=time&minmag=5&limit=10 >

See my code for connecting and fetching the data

```
package com.example.android.quakereport;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class QueryUtils {
    //create tag for the log messages
    public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

     //Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.

    private QueryUtils() {
    }

    //Query the USGS data set to return an Earthquake object
    public static List<Earthquake> fetchEarthquakeData(String requestUrl){
        //create a url from the string url provided
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

        //make Http request on the url created and receive json response back
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try{
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "return Data " + jsonResponse );
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error Closing input Stream");
        }

        return extractFeatureFromJSON(jsonResponse);
    }


    //create a url fro the given url string
    private static URL createUrl(String StringUrl){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(StringUrl);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Malformed Url", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    //make http request from the url created to return as a json string
    private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException{
        String jsonResponse = "";

        //if the url is null, then return early
        if (url == null){
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try{
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* im milliseconds*/);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /*in milliseconds*/);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            //if the connection was successful i.e response code = 200
            //then read the input stream and pass the response
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            }
            else{
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Response Error Code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem Retrieving the earthquake Json results");
        }
        finally {
            if (urlConnection != null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null){
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    //convert the input stream into a String which has the whole json response
    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if(inputStream != null){
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line != null){
                line = reader.readLine();
                output.append(line);
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    //Return a list of {@link Earthquake} objects that has been built up from
    private static List<Earthquake> extractFeatureFromJSON(String eartquakeJSON) {
        //if the json string is empty or null, then return early
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(eartquakeJSON)){
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
        ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {
            //create the JSON object of the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE
            JSONObject EarthquakeObject = new JSONObject(eartquakeJSON);
            //get the features JSON array
            JSONArray featuresArray = EarthquakeObject.getJSONArray("features");

            //loop through the features array
            for (int i = 0; i < featuresArray.length(); i++) {
                //get the JSON object at position i
                JSONObject currentEarthquakeDetails = featuresArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //get the JSON properties of the current object
                JSONObject properties = currentEarthquakeDetails.getJSONObject("properties");

                //get the magnitude of the current earthquate details
                double magnitude = properties.getDouble("mag");

                //get the location of the current earthquake details
                String location = properties.getString("place");

                //get the time of the current earthquake details
                long time = properties.getLong("time");
                Date dateObject = new Date(time);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM DD, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                String dateToDisplay = dateFormater.format(dateObject);

                String url = properties.getString("url");

                earthquakes.add(new Earthquake(magnitude, location, dateToDisplay, url));
            }
            // TODO: Parse the response given by the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE string and
            // build up a list of Earthquake objects with the corresponding data.

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of earthquakes
        return earthquakes;

    }
}
```

Also See my Main Activity Code

```
package com.example.android.quakereport;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Sample JSON response for a USGS query
     */
    private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&orderby=time&minmag=5&limit=10";

    private EarthquakeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();
        // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
        adapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this, earthquakes);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set onclick listener to each item on the listView
        earthquakeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l){
                //Get the current earthquake that was clicked
                Earthquake currentEarthquake = earthquakes.get(position);
                Intent browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentEarthquake.getUrl()));
                startActivity(browse);
            }
        });

        EarthquakeAsyncTask task = new EarthquakeAsyncTask();
        task.execute(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
    }

    private class EarthquakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Earthquake>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Earthquake> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //check if the url is empty
            if (urls.length < 0 || urls[0] == null){
                return null;
            }
            return QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Earthquake> data){
            //Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
            adapter.clear();

            //if data is null then return empty
            if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
                adapter.addAll(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Also my Log Cat

> 11-02 08:41:15.049 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:15.055 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:15.075 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:15.089 1710-1838/? E/UsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:41:15.089 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:15.092 1710-1838/? E/CsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:41:24.008 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:24.021 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:24.027 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:24.029 1710-1838/? E/UsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:41:24.030 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:41:24.033 1710-1838/? E/CsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:41:32.988 1665-1665/? E/InputEventModelImpl: onStartInput event aborted: com.touchtype.keyboard.c.ag: could not obtain extracted text (class com.touchtype.keyboard.c.ag)
>   11-02 08:41:33.977 898-898/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: ENABLE_TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL false Token 847
>   11-02 08:41:33.980 30524-30524/? E/hostapd: Line 0: unknown configuration item 'pno'
>   11-02 08:41:33.980 898-945/? E/WifiStateMachine:  Fail to set up pno, want false now false
>   11-02 08:41:34.309 898-945/? E/WifiStateMachine: Error! unhandled message{ when=-2ms what=131156 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
>   11-02 08:42:26.243 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.249 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.253 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.256 1710-1838/? E/UsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:42:26.256 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.259 1710-1838/? E/CsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:42:26.346 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.349 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.353 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.357 1710-1838/? E/UsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:42:26.357 1710-1838/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   11-02 08:42:26.360 1710-1838/? E/CsimAccountType: [addDataKindEmail]for AAS.
>   11-02 08:42:26.363 898-1757/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
>   11-02 08:42:26.369 898-1757/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
>   11-02 08:42:26.382 898-1757/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(200000000)m, error(0), index(2)

Comment: have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: The problem might be that you don't tell your adapter to rebuild the list after `adapter.addAll(data);`. Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging it, and I noticed the url is redirecting i.e error 301, I have changed the url but still doing same.

Comment: I have also added the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but still no change

Comment: then firstly localize the problem. Check at least where the data is not arriving.